# How do I get the values from a repeating promise from an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I have an API call that I am making to a service that keeps giving me results until it is done. So when I run this in my code it will list each item as it is pushed into the array

```
   const faxList = [];
   client.fax.faxes.each((faxes) => {
     faxList.push(faxes);
     console.log(faxList);
   });
```

Outputs:

```
[ '0' ]
[ '0',  '1' ]
[ '0',  '1',  '2' ]
[ '0',  '1',  '2',  '3' ]
```

How do I wait for that loop to complete and then return the completed array? The goal is to get `faxList` as a usable variable that I can use. For example to send via express. I have tried with async/await but that just outputs the first result before completing. Same result using then/catch. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I have an API call that I am making to a service that keeps giving me results until it is done."* Can you provide a better example of that? Or are you just making the API inside your `.each` callback? Or does  `.each` make the API call?

Comment: Yes, it is a function from the twilio npm package. Here is the example I'm pulling from: https://www.twilio.com/docs/fax/api/faxes#list-get-example-1
As mentioned it works on its own and will list everything needed. I just need to know how I can make node wait for the entire promise/loop complete so that I can have the completed array.

The response from twilio sends each value back one at a time in their response. That's the downside

Comment: Is there documentation about the JS API somewhere?

Comment: It seems `.each` accepts an object with `done` property which would be called when all records have been received. https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/1814d572fc7c258b69e3c8d8c11426f202ad7860/examples/example.js#L13-L26

Comment: Or maybe you can use `.list` instead of `.each`: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/1814d572fc7c258b69e3c8d8c11426f202ad7860/examples/example.js#L125

Comment: Sadly those examples are pretty out of date with their current project. Running those commands work to an extent but don't have the same functionality. For example running the .each version linked above only returns one result. If you want to see what the `.each` from my original post does you can see it directly in their source: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/lib/rest/fax/v1/fax.js

interestingly enough that entire api function was added after the last time they updated their examples. I bet they are just updating on their reference now instead of directly in the repo.

Comment: The source looks like it supports the two things I mentioned though. `.each` accepts an object with a `done` property and `.list` also exists.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the flow of things here. Even when I add a done property it just gives me a type error TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined when put in the normal flow of a promise and if put directly in the call itself it just cuts the connection short without finishing the call.

Comment: Does `client.fax.faxes.list().then(faxes => console.log(faxes))` not work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173655/discussion-between-phillip-and-felix-kling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific problem with the twilio client, you can use the `.list` method instead. It will return a promise that resolves an array of records:

```
client.fax.faxes.list().then(faxes => console.log(faxes));
```

---

A more general approach requires that the API provides at least

- a way to get each value
- a way to be notified when all values have been fetched (i.e. the API is "done)

In the following example we have a hypothetical API that triggers two events, `data` when a value is available and `done` when all values have been fetched.

The general approach to "wrap" a Promise around this API call. We collect the values in an array and resolve the promise when the API is done.

```
function fetchData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const values = [];

    someAPI.fetch({
      data: value => values.push(value),
      done: () => resolve(value),
      error: error => reject(error),
    });

  });
}

// Then used as
fetchData().then(values => console.log(values));
```

Again, how to do this concretely depends on how the API in question works.